# Strange Timeout WebException in HTTP Get using WebClient

Tags: c#, multithreading, timeout, webclient, httpwebresponse

I have a multi-thread application (in c#) that it does multiples HTTP `GET` to uri. Suddenly after of thousand of requests, i get timeout webException but destination server is OK if i test using browser. The code is:

```
public static string Get(string uri)
{
    string responseData = string.Empty;
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        responseData = wc.DownloadString(uri);
    }
    return responseData;
}
```

I think it is dispose connection issue or similar error. Any body has same problem?

Thx in advance,

PS I have used `HttpWebResponse` too. But i get same error.

PS OS is Windows 2003 server. So i think is not connection limits.

I have try with this code too and i get same error

```
  public static string Get2(string uri)
    {
        string responseData = string.Empty;                
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Timeout = 35000;    
        using(HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {                   
            using(Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ())
            {                   
                using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream))
                {
                    responseData = reader.ReadToEnd();                      
                }
            }
        }           
        return responseData;
    }
```

Comment: Is the server you're making the requests to on your network or remote?

Comment: yes, destination server is remote

Comment: How many requests per second are you making?

Comment: I do 50 http get simultaneously and each request hava a duration of 1 o 2 seconds when all is ok. When it had done more 10k then timeout

Answer (score 0):

Quick question(s)

1. Is the server also your code?
2. How many are *multiple* requests?
3. Try ping -t on your server and
   see if any packet loss is reported
   from your client machine.

Have you thought of maybe the server exhausts all its resources handling your requests and just plain and simple restarts itself. Thats why you get a timeout when you are doing a query but by the time you do the browser *ping*, it is back up. Just a thought

Since, you mention "thousands of requests", I am more inclined to think a resource crunch on the server rather than a connectivity issue.

Comment: 1) There are two different server. Mine for request and destination is always running.
2) I get the error from 12K request.

Yes i think it is a connection dispose problem, but i use using {}. If i restart application, then all is ok until reach 10K request.

Comment: do you have access to server logs? Having a "connection problem" after about 10K problem does not *sound* right to me. It looks to me like a resource crunch. Can you try running wireshark with http filter at the time you are experiencing these timeouts

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by any number of reasons including:

- Brief transient loss of connectivity
  between your application and the
  remote web server
- The remote server is possibly not responding in time due to load

I suggest setting a longer timeout on the request but you'd need to use [`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) instead because there is no way to set a timeout on `WebClient`.

Comment: I think those are not problem. Because i can Get using browser while i get the error (exist a retry function). Timeout throw at 00:01:40.  I have try using HttpWebResponse with high Timeout too and i get same error.

Answer (score 0):

Having faced this myself what I found to work is to try your get request a few more times after a short Wait() on that thread for say 5 seconds and if it doesn't work it is best to leave the server alone for some time. :-)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is **Port Exhaustion**.

You are creating a new WebClient on each new request. This means it will grab a new TCP connection and port on every request. On a windows machine ports are only in the 16 bit range so 0 - 65535 and the OS imposes further resictions on this range.

If you do a `NETSTAT -on` a on your Windows machine, you'll see a list of connections and their assigned ports.

The issue is that ports are only returned after >30s as they enter a `TIME_WAIT` state. This means if you making a new request every <30s you will eventually run out of ports and bad things will happen.

I recommend creating a single WebClient and reusing it. Not only can you avoid the above described issue but it is also more performant.